# Когда возникает событие onpopstate

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Играюсь с History API и не могу понять, когда возникает событие popstate. Поставил простой алерт на него, получил такие результаты:

- Нажатие "вперед", "назад" в браузере - вызывают.
- Нажатие на ссылку - не вызывают.
- Прямая запись в location.href - не вызывает
- Дозапись (+=) в location.href - вызывает.
- Запись через pushState - вопреки статьям в интернете, не вызывает.

Абсолютно не могу понять логику. А может её и нет?

А вообще мне хотелось бы отловить вообще любые переходы. Я это уже делал с помощью onclick на ссылке, но это не удобно. Ладно ещё при инициализации пройтись по всем `<a>`шкам, но если контент может генерироваться динамически это  накладывает определённые проблемы (скорее даже неудобства, чем проблемы). Возможно ли это сделать "красиво"?

Comment: По моей практике, вызывают только «вперед» и «назад», а по pushState не вызывает ни один браузер и только, ЕМНИП, Safari зачем-то вызывает (но лучше перепроверить)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
history.pushState({page: 1}, "title 1", "?page=1");
history.pushState({page: 2}, "title 2", "?page=2");
history.replaceState({page: 3}, "title 3", "?page=3");
history.back(); // Logs "location: example.com/example.html?page=1, state: {"page":1}"
history.back(); // Logs "location: example.com/example.html, state: null
history.go(2);  // Logs "location: example.com/example.html?page=3, state: {"page":3}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Хороший пример, спасибо ) Меня просто сбило с толку то, что запись в href иногда дает popstate.